# Estimating the number of integers less than $m$ that are relatively prime to $p_n\#$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, gcd-and-lcm, primorial

Let $m \ge 2$ be an integer.

Let $p_n$ be the $n$th prime so that $p_1 = 2, p_2 = 3,$ etc.

Let $p_n\#$ be the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) for $p_n$.

Let $\gcd(a,b)$ be the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) for $a$ and $b$.

Let $f(m,p_n) =$ the number of integers $x$ where $0 < x \le m$ and $\gcd(x,p_n\#)=1$

For example:

- $f(10,2)=5$
- $f(10,3)=3$

It seems to me that $f(m,p_n)$ can be estimated in the following way:

$$\left\lfloor\left(\prod\limits_{p_i \le p_n}\frac{p_i-1}{p_i}\right)m\right\rfloor \le f(m,p_n) \le \left\lceil\left(\prod\limits_{p_i \le p_n}\frac{p_i-1}{p_i}\right)m\right\rceil$$

Here's my argument:

For any $m$:

- at least $\left\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\right\rfloor$ are odd
- at least $\left\lfloor\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\left(\frac{m}{2}\right)\right\rfloor$ are odd and not divisible by $3$,
- at least $\left\lfloor\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\left(\frac{m}{2}\right)\right\rfloor$ are odd, not divisible by $3$ and not divisible by $5$.
- and so on.
- at most $\left\lceil\frac{m}{2}\right\rceil$ are odd.
- and so on in the same way.

Is my reasoning valid?  If yes, what is the standard argument?  If my reasoning is not valid, could you provide a counter example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct, you are basically applying inclusion-exclusion formula. There are at least two kind of generalizations of the problem you mentioned above:

1. Given pairwise coprime positive integers $a_1,\ldots,a_k$, then the number of positive integers $n\le x$ coprime with each $a_i$ admits asymptotic density
   $$
   \left(1-\frac{1}{a_1}\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{1}{a_k}\right).
   $$
2. Given positive integers $a_1,\ldots,a_k$, then the number of positive integers $n\le x$ not divisible by each $a_i$ admits asymptotic density
   $$
   \ge \left(1-\frac{1}{a_1}\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{1}{a_k}\right).
   $$
   For a proof see [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/on-an-inequality-in-the-elementary-theory-of-numbers/E2272208919A42A86A4502EEC0269EFB) and a textbook exposition [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521109922).

Comment: Thanks very much for your explanation and providing references to the proof!  :-)

Comment: Under what conditions will this not be true?  It has been pointed out that the inequality fails for $f(10,7)$ which equals $1$ but $\left\lfloor\left(\prod\limits_{p \le 7}\frac{p-1}{p}\right)10\right\rfloor = 2$

Comment: @LarryFreeman the value $\prod_i \left(1-\frac{1}{a_i}\right)$ expresses the (natural) asymptotic density of the set of integers $n$ with the property of not being divisible by any $a_i$. Of course, the problem is periodic modulo $\mathrm{lcm}(a_1,\ldots,a_k)$. Therefore, you could say that $f(n,p_k\#)=\lfloor n/p_k\#\rfloor \prod_{i=1}^k ((p_i-1)/p_i)+\mathrm{error}$, with $\mathrm{error} \in \{0,1,\ldots,\varphi(p_k\#)-1\}$ (here $\varphi$ is the Euler's function).

Comment: Thanks very much for the clarification!  That makes sense.